# Tangent Vector at a specific point

Tags: calculus, vectors, tangent-line

I was asked to parameterize the **circle edge** of $d_2 =\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=9$ and $x+y\ge0\}.$

[image]

Anyways I parametrized the circle edge within the bounds but now I have to find the tangent vector at $(0, 3)$ and I am not exactly sure how to do that. Would I set $(-3\cos(t), 3\sin(t))$ equal to its bounds then solve first? Like $-3\cos(t)=\pi/4, 3\sin(t)=5\pi/4$ and then find $r'(t)$?

Comment: You can parametrize the curve as $r(t) = (3 \cos t, 3 \sin t)$. Then tangent vector is nothing but $r'(t)$. At $(0,3), t = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: also given $x+y \geq 0, - \frac{\pi}{4} \leq t \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Why can it be done at (3cost,3sint) when that breaks the domain x+y>=0? What do I do with the (0,3)?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. That is regular parametrization of the circle and you set the bounds of $t$ in line with the constraint $x+y \geq 0$ which is $- \frac{\pi}{4} \leq t \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: How do we get $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$? That is from $(0,3)$, correct?

Comment: Look at my picture I cant have my parameterization outside of that green section

Comment: I dont know how you got pi/2

Comment: look at the limits of $t$ I wrote. Does that go outside your green section?

Comment: Nope that looks like it works as well! Now how exactly would I parameterize it at (0,3)?

Comment: if the parametrization is $(3 \cos t, 3 \sin t)$, how do you find $t$ at $(0, 3)$? Equate $3 \cos t = 0, 3 \sin t = 3$, what values of $t$ satisfy both?

Comment: Does <-3t, 3> work? Or <-t, 3>?

Comment: No that is wrong. What value of $t$ do you get for $(0,3)$? See my earlier comment.

Comment: Well 3cos(-pi/4) = 3sqrt(2) / 2 and 3sin(3pi/4) also equals 3sqart(2) / 2

Comment: This is too long a conversation for comments and we have a warning. I have moved this to chat. We can discuss further there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120185/discussion-between-math-lover-and-unsure).